# Why is CAS using the server SSL private key?

Tags: ssl-certificate, cas, weblogic-10.x, private-key

I'm looking into a jasig CAS installation on a WebLogic server.

In the past, WL was serving SSL for the CAS-Server. Now, the SSL layer is provided by load balancer. And we use a new server certificate (the former has expired)

So SSL is deactivated on WL.
But the identity configuration and the SSL configuration still remains for the alias "casserver" That identity configuration, shouldn't being used. Because SSL is deactivated.

But something is happening because WL says the opposite:

CAS: 2015-05-29 09:00:10,353 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - (Granted service ticket [ST-xxxyyyzzz-cas] for service [https://myweb/root-context/j_spring_cas_security_check] for user [john.doe])
(29-may-2015 09H00' CEST) (Alert) (Security) (BEA-090154) (Identity certificate has expired: [
... SerialNumber: the-former-certificate-serial-number

And I also find more references to the former keystore and the former SSL certificate alias:

CAS: 2015-05-27 14:00:33,611 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - (AuthenticationHandler: org.jasig.cas.adaptors.x509.authenticat
ion.handler.support.X509CredentialsAuthenticationHandler successfully authenticated the user which provided the following credentials: org.jasig.cas.adaptor
s.x509.authentication.principal.X509CertificateCredentials@12341234)
(27-may-2015 14H00' CEST) (Notice) (Security) (BEA-090171) (Loading the identity certificate and private key stored under the alias **casserver** fr
om the JKS keystore file **/.../old-identity-keystore.jks**.)

Why is WL loading the keystore with each request?

How is it still working with an expired certificate?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you uncheck `SSL Listen Port Enabled` for your server? Did you uncheck `Use Server Certs` in your server SSL tab?

Comment: "SSL Listen Port Enabled" was unchecked. And there were no "User Server Certs" in Environment -> Servers -> <server> -> SSL, expanded "Advanced".  I'm using WL 10.0 M1 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I removed the SSL alias.  There were no reason to use it, because SSL is disabled.

Now, there are warnings saying that there are no alias.  But the system works correctly (as expected)

I think that WL is trying to setup it's SSL certificate during the load of the SSL layer, every time I ask to create SSL conections (despite I'm going to use SSL as a client).